req.headers.auth is undefined In jwt and express js
I'm new to use jwt library ..
So I made a login form and if it success it generates token and verify but it generates token and respond that token , but I can't get that token in req.headers.authorization , i tried req.headers['authorization'] also , it shows undefined and I console logs req.headers it gives like host , connection , origin , accept , referrer , cookie ...i try to add Authorization with token in my routes like this req.headers.authorization = token , it stores but can't get it ...
verify token.js
import { user } from './models/users.js'; 
export const verifyToken = async (req, res, next) => {
  const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
  
  if (!authHeader) {
    return res.status(401).send('Token is missing');
  }

  const token = authHeader.split('   ')[1];
  if (!token)
    return res.status(401).send('Token is missing');
  }

  try {
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY, async (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Token verification error:', err);
        return res.status(403).send('Invalid token');
      }
      const user1 = await user.findOne({ id: decoded.id });
      if (!user1) {
        return res.status(404).send('User not found');
      }

      req.user = user1;
      next();
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error in verifyToken middleware:', e);
    return res.status(500).send('Server error');
  }
};

GenerateToken.js
export const generateToken = (user) => {
  try {
    return jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, process.env.SECRET_KEY, { expiresIn: '30m' });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error generating token:', e);
  }
};

const router = express.Router();
routes.get('/' ,  startpage)
router.post('/register', register);
router.post('/login', login);
router.get('/home', verifyToken, homepage);
router.get('/buynow', verifyToken, buynow);

Here ,  / -> Startpage has two forms
Login form , register form
Loginform -> post method and /login action
Registerform -> post method and /register action
I use generateToken function on /login and it gives token./home -> will renders a home ejs file
I use generateToken () function in /login route
Like : let token= generateToken(userVar)
Token is generated correctly
It gives the token and but I can't verify it , it responds missing token , but it can't get req.headers.authorization and it displays undefined

How is the token supposed to end up in that header in the first place? Is there some sort of automatism in place that would add it to every request you make from the client side?

You have to add Token to request header from client side.
After Login you will get token
Set that token in Localstorage
When calling api get the token from Localstorage and set in Authorization header.
eg:
var token = localStorage.getItem('token');

fetch('/dashboard', {
   headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   }
})

Then the NodeJs program can access req.headers['authorization']
Tip:
You can use cookies inorder to avoid this manual setting of token in request header.
Browser will send cookies automatically with every request.

Thank u so much , i use cookies

Hi, Can you please see the cookie bearing the token has shown stored under Application/Storage/Cookies (in Google Chrome).
